# LLenado un DataGrid WPF Manualmente

Tags: c#

Como crear un dataGrid vacio,para poder despues rellenarlo manual mente,le he puesto la propiedad CanUserAddRows="True",pero no me funciona.Aqui estas este sencillo codigo

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="True" ColumnWidth="*" GridLinesVisibility="All" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn  Header="First Name"  FontFamily="Arial" FontStyle="Italic" />
            <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Last Name"   FontFamily="Arial" FontWeight="Bold" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pon la propiedad `CanUserAddRows = "False"` y con eso se soluciona. Saludos!

**Editado:**

Para poder realizar lo que necesitas primero create una clase por ejemplo: `MiClaseDymmy.cs` que contenga la definicion de las columnas que necesitas y un constructor vacío:

```
 class MiClaseDummy
{
    
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    
 
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public MiClaseDummy()
    {

    }
}
```

Entonces en el constructor del Mainwindow generas el source inicial de la siguiente manera:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

       gridDemo.ItemsSource = new List<MiClaseDummy>() { };
    }


  
}
```

y por ultimo en tu XAML deberas eliminar las columnas y activar la autogeneracion de columnas `AutoGenerateColumns="True"` y darle un nombre por ejemplo: `gridDemo` de la siguiente manera:

```
 <Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="gridDemo" AutoGenerateColumns="True" CanUserAddRows="True" ColumnWidth="*" GridLinesVisibility="All" >
       
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Espero que te sirva, saludos!

Comment: Gracias Enoch,pero no me sirve,no aparece las filas para poder escribir

Comment: Gracias Enoch,pero no me sirve,no aparece las filas para escribir,he visto que en WindowForm,cuando crea un DataGridView,,si se crea filas para poder escribir.Pero en WPF no,que es lo que me falta,que propiedad,me falta,gracias

Comment: Te volví a editar la respuesta, espero que te sirva, saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias,no lo habia visto por tiempo del trabajo.Me sirvio